# How do i use user_passes_test view specific page?

Tags: python, django, django-views, python-decorators

**My User Model**

```
SELLER = "SELLER"
CUSTOMER = "CUSTOMER"
USER_TYPE_CHOICES = (
    ('SELLER' , 'Seller'),
    ('CUSTOMER' , 'Customer'),    
)
class User(AbstractBaseUser,PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField( max_length=255, unique=True)
    user_type = models.CharField(max_length=200,choices=USER_TYPE_CHOICES,null=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField( blank=True, null=True)


    is_staff = models.BooleanField( default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField( default=False)

    is_active = models.BooleanField( default=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['email']

    def clean(self):
        super().clean()
        self.email = self.__class__.objects.normalize_email(self.email)

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.email

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.email
```

**I have two user_types one seller and one customer how i can use user_passes_test decorator to see if the user.user_type is seller so he can see the seller view only seller can see the seller view**

```
def seller_home(request,pk):
    try:
        seller =  Seller.objects.get(id=pk)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("Seller Does Not Exisit")
    
    sellerproducts = Product.objects.filter(seller=seller)
    totalsellerproducts = sellerproducts.count()
    context = {'seller':seller,'sellerproducts':sellerproducts,"totalsellerproducts":totalsellerproducts }
    return render(request,"seller_home.html",context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can't, because `user_passes_test` is for authenticated users only, so the seller or customer cannot be sent by URL to the view, because it will be insecure, anyone will be able to test any pk, You must use the authenticated user in `request.user` to do this, then the decorator will be easy. Something like this:

```
def seller_check(user):
    return user.user_type == User.SELLER

@user_passes_test(seller_check)
def seller_home(request):
    pass
```

Comment: thanks its working but one more question if i sign in as seller or customer once i am signed in that user type i can access all that type of users  if i want to but i want to restirict it also so only loged in user can access itself not anyone else can you tell me ?

Comment: i suppose that you are trying to restrict the view only for authenticated users right? if the answer is yes you can edit the `seller_check` function implementation to something like this `return user.user_type == User.SELLER and user.is_authenticated`. If this fail, will send the user to `settings.LOGIN_URL` by default or you can edit with a param in user_passes_test `login_url='/login/'`